# Timer vs ASIHTTPRequest - find optimal solution

Tags: ios, asihttprequest, nstimer

The code is shown as below, I have a button once you click it activates timer and timer calls method every 4sec. However, sometimes 4 sec is not enough for server to return the data. However, increasing the timer value is not also good solution if server returns data in 1 sec and would not good for user to wait longer. I do not know what is best/optimal solution in this case.

```
-(IBAction)play:(id)sender{
    timer=[NSTimer scheculedWith TimerInterval(4.0) target:(self)selector:@selector(httpRequest) userinfo:nil repeats:YES]
    }
    -(void)httpRequest{

    _weak ASIHTTPRequest *request1 = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [request1 setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *responseString1 = [request1 responseString];
    //dispatch_async(backgroundProcess1,^(void){
        [self plotOverlay1:responseString1];
     //});
    }];
    [request1 setFailedBlock:^{
        NSError *error=[request1 error];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    }]; 

    [request1 startAsynchronous];
    }
```

Comment: Instead of using a timer, could you just call httpRequest again from the completion block?  That way a new request will be made as soon as the previous one completes.  Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Jon,could u please take a look at my question that I have just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594112/remove-annotation-from-mapview-like-google-map-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the data to be updating continuously, consider calling `-httpRequest` again from within the completion block of the first request (and removing the timer). That way, you can be assured that the request will get performed again, but only *after* the first request finishes - and you can introduce a delay there, so you get something like "check again two seconds after the first check finishes."

This might look something like:

```
- (void)httpRequest {
    __weak ASIHTTPRequest *req = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url1];
    [req setCompletionBlock:^{
        NSString *resp = [req responseString];
        [self plotOverlay1:resp];

        [self httpRequest];
        // or...
        [self performSelector:@selector(httpRequest) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
    }];
    /* snip fail block */
    [req startAsynchronous];
}
```

Comment: Hello Tim,could u please take a look at my question that I have just posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594112/remove-annotation-from-mapview-like-google-map-app

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611080/google-app-thumbnail-map-image-mkannotation