# How to go to second view controller after click on disclosure indicator button

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, mkannotation

I would like to remove existing annotation from mapview. Scenerio is to click on existing annotation callout part (disclosureindicator button) and it would lead user to another viewcontroller and shows a button you could remove the selected annotation. Actually, I am working on to create exactly same google map application, that is part I am struggling now. Any help would be appreciated! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MKMapView class has two methods you need to add/remove annotations:

```
addAnnotation: id <MKAnnotation>
removeAnnotation: id <MKAnnotation>
```

You'd create a class that implements the protocol MKAnnotation. Here's an example in another SO question: [MKAnnotation, simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495419/mkannotation-simple-example)

Comment: my question is to know how to go to second view controller once I click on disclosure indicator button on the top of the annotation. removing/adding annotation is quite simple.

Comment: Ok that wasn't clear. So when you tap on the disclosure you need to implement this in your mapview delegate:

- (void) mapView: (MKMapView*) mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control;

From this function you could allocate a new view for example and push it to a navigation controller, or present it modally, really there are many options to follow, so you'll have to be more specific.

Comment: oki, superr I got it. thanks a lot. I would like to ask how you get the portion of the map above showing in the second viewcontroller above.?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12611080/google-app-thumbnail-map-image-mkannotation